# Docker & R (renv): RUN package installations not found when running container

Tags: r, docker, renv

My Dockerfile uses renv and I have the following RUN command (whole file here: https://github.com/chpatola/docker-r-tutorial/blob/main/local_file/Dockerfile)

```
RUN Rscript -e "renv::restore(prompt = FALSE)"
```

When it is run as I build the image, I get this message:

> The library is already synchronized with the lockfile.

However, when I run a container from the image and start R (docker run -it -v "$(pwd):/usr/src/orders" --name data_cont handle_data), I get these messages:

> The following package(s) have broken symlinks into the cache:
>
> assertthat, cli, crayon, digest, dplyr, ellipsis, fansi,  generics,
> glue, lifecycle, lubridate, magrittr, pillar,     pkgconfig, purrr, R6,
> Rcpp, rlang, tibble, tidyselect,  utf8, vctrs
>
> Use `renv::repair()` to try and reinstall these packages.
>
> - The project may be out of sync -- use `renv::status()` for more details.
>   Warning message:
>   The following package(s) are missing entries in the cache:
>
>   assertthat, cli, crayon, digest, dplyr, ellipsis, fansi,
>   generics, glue, lifecycle, lubridate, magrittr, pillar,
>   pkgconfig, purrr, R6, Rcpp, rlang, tibble, tidyselect,
>   utf8, vctrs
>
>   These packages will need to be reinstalled.

I do not understand what has gone wrong here. On my dev computer, I called `renv::init()` and then `renv::isolate()`. What can I do to get the package installation from `renv::restore()` to instal the packages properly so they can be loaded normally when the container is run? Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the full command syntax that you apply when running the image?

Comment: added :) docker run -it -v "$(pwd):/usr/src/orders" --name data_cont handle_data